# How to retrieve Sqlite database values in a getter-setter class in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, getter-setter

I am using an `ArrayAdapter` to generate the contents of a `DrawerLayout` to get a `SliderMenu`. The first row of my SliderMenu gets the picture from the `sdcard` whose path is saved in the `Sqlite` database. I am using a getter and setter class named   `DrawerItem` . I am trying to retrieve the path from the database in the getter setter class. My codes are as follows. Please guide me step by step:

DrawerItem.class

```
  public class DrawerItem {

String ItemName,Fbid;
int imgResID;
 Bitmap bmp;
 File f;
 Databasehandler2 db=new Databasehandler2(null);
public DrawerItem()
{

}
public DrawerItem(String itemName, int imgResID) {
    super();
    ItemName = itemName;
    this.imgResID = imgResID;
}

public DrawerItem(String itemName, Bitmap bmp) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    ItemName = itemName;
    HashMap<String, String>details=new HashMap<String, String>();
    details=db.mydetails();
    String p=details.get("fbid");
    Log.i("draweritem",""+details.get("fbid"));
    File f = new File("/mnt/sdcard/TaskManager/test210000.png");

    Bitmap bmps = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
    this.bmp = bmps;
}


public String getItemName() {
    return ItemName;
}
public void setItemName(String itemName) {
    ItemName = itemName;
}
public int getImgResID() {
    return imgResID;
}
public void setImgResID(int imgResID) {
    this.imgResID = imgResID;
}

public String getfbid() {
    return Fbid;
}
public void setfbid(String fbid) {
    Fbid = fbid;
}

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First your code is really messy.  Some sets you use this. others your captilise. Make sure your coding style is consistent.  Secondly, why are you saving the string reference to the image? And why specifically on the SD card? Why not just save the byte[]?